# Gerrit Local setup and creating a first change and plugin

Tags: git, gerrit

I have setup the latest Gerrit tool 2.11.4 on my local machine and initialized the site successfully.

I have registered two users using OPENID authorization one admin and one regular user.

I created a git local repo and initialized it empty.

Now I have cloned this repo from Gerrit to my local location using ssh url.

After adding the changes when I push the changes for review I get an error that no changeID exists.

Can someone show me the git steps to create the change and push to the review branch with some reference.

Another question which I have is what plugins I need to view my code on gerrit site to do a side by side comparison and write a review/question/comment.

Thank you for the help, I am trying the follow the documentation but does not seem to be working for me when creating a change.

Answer (score 0):

Steps for creating a change:

1. Run the below command to get hooks copied to your local git repo, it will help you change to add change-id to it:

> **scp -p -P 29418 gerrit-url:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/**

2. Made a change in any file, add it and commit

> git add -u
>
> git commit -m "Your Message for commit"

3. Run the below command to push your change to gerrit

> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch-name

With this you are done with pushing your changes to gerrit. Enjoy :)

**Note:** Regarding your second question, i don't think anyother pluggin is required since gerrit by-default has side-by-side diff option.

Feel free to ask any further queries!!